# how Can I Sort multiple root node hierarchy in a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, parent-child, hierarchy

I have the following heirarchies in the DB

```
A (1)
|_A1 (2)
|  |_A11 (1)
|
|_A2 (1)
```

and

```
B (5)
|_B1 (3)
|
|_B2 (1)
   |_B21 (2)
   |_B22 (3)
```

I can make results like this

```
Parent    Child   Views
A          A1       2
A1         A11      1
A          A2       1
B          B1       3
B          B2       1
B2         B21      2
B2         B22      3
```

using following query

```
with w(child, parent, views) as
(
  select 'A', null, 1 from dual
  union all
  select 'A1', 'A', 2 from dual
  union all
  select 'A11', 'A1', 1 from dual
  union all
  select 'A2', 'A', 1 from dual
  union all
  select 'B', null, 5 from dual
  union all
  select 'B1', 'B', 3 from dual
  union all
  select 'B2', 'B', 1 from dual
  union all
  select 'B21', 'B2', 2 from dual
  union all
  select 'B22', 'B2', 3 from dual
)
select parent, child
from w
where level >1
connect by w.parent = prior w.child
start with w.parent is null
;
```

Now, I want order by views desc between ('B', null, 5) and ('A',null,1) before start with~  like below results

```
Parent    Child     Views
B          B1         3
B          B2         1   
B2         B21        2
B2         B22        3
A          A1         2
A1         A11        1
A          A2         1
```

I tried change position insert query 'A' and 'B', but it was not effective.

Which way I can search hierarchy start 'B', Not 'A'

I had trouble with it all day. please help me

Comment: I would recommend you move on to the modern "recursive CTEs" instead of using the old school "connect by".

Comment: @TheImpaler - just as a matter of interest, will converting to a recursive WITH clause make it easier to solve this problem?

Comment: "...between ('B', null, 5) and ('A',null,1)..." - Table rows do not have inherent ordering. The "between" selection must be further qualified to make sense.

Comment: Recursive CTEs are more common nowadays (read: more people understand them) and they also offer you a wider repertoire of options. Some people say the old "connect by" is faster, but I haven't personally witnessed this.